# Strange Error with Calling a Typescript Function

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript class and a function in this class that is actually calling another function in another Typescript class:

[image]

The get method that I'm calling looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this is an issue here? Why am I not able to call the get function?

Comment: Try adding `urlParams.set('rawParams','test')`

Comment: Why? and What is that?

Comment: I did, but still the same problem!

Comment: Can you add the code definition for `URLSearchParams` to the question?

Comment: What do you mean by code definition?

Comment: The default `URLSearchParams` don't have the `rawParams` property (as shown in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20URLSearchParams%3B%0Aconsole.log(a.rawParams)%3B)). Where do you get the definition that do have it from?

Comment: The one that I use comes from the url_search_parameters.d.ts file

Comment: Well then, you have a conflict. You probably just have two different definitions for this type and that confuses the compiler. Stop using `url_search_parameters.d.ts` and the error will probably go away. Another thing, please edit your question and add the code in text, image links can break in the future and not as readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Strange Error with Calling a Typescript Function

You have two *incompatible* `URLSearchParams` classes in your project. Delete one